# PHPSpreadsheet: getHighestDataRow/getHighestDataColumn after fromArray

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I'm using fromArray to load an array of data into a worksheet. This is working fine. After doing so, getHighestDataColumn and getHighestDataRow do not seem to be updated. Is there a way to force PHPSpreadsheet to recalculate these values after calling fromArray?

[edit] An update seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: please share snippets of your code where you populate the sheet using `fromArray` and use `getHighestDataColumn` and `getHighestDataRow`

Comment: @ggordon: An update seems to have fixed my issue, but I can't remove the question due to an open bounty. If you want to post a simple example of using fromArray, getHighestDataColumn, and getHighestDataRow, I'll accept the answer for the bounty.

Comment: You should tell (others) what you upgraded from and to.  Then close the question.

Comment: I updated PHPSpreadsheet itself and the problem cleared up. I am currently on 1.14.1. I don't see anything in the changelog that would have affected this, so I'm not sure what caused the original issue. I was unable to do anything with the question because of the open bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware to not use the [github#PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) lib if you're still using them. 
They've said to update to its directly successor, which is beig maintained and recently updated at [github#PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet)

Recently Microsoft released an update which breaks some of the functionalities when we use the old lib.

Getting this example from their doc, you could try using the [fromArray()](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/accessing-cells/#setting-a-range-of-cells-from-an-array):

To set data from an array:

```
$arrayData = [
  [NULL, 2010, 2011, 2012],
  ['Q1',   12,   15,   21],
  ['Q2',   56,   73,   86],
  ['Q3',   52,   61,   69],
  ['Q4',   30,   32,    0],
];
$sheet->getActiveSheet()
  ->fromArray(
    $arrayData,  // The data to set
    NULL,        // Array values with this value will not be set
    'C3'         // Top left coordinate of the worksheet range where
                //    we want to set these values (default is A1)
  );
```

Then you follow this to extract data from the spreadsheet:

```
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

//  Loop for each row
for ($row = 0; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
  // here you extract the columns for that row
  $columns = array_shift(array_values($sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE)));
}
```